# Worklight JMS Adapter Issue

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I'm trying to use worklight jms adpater with Websphere MQ Provider. 
Steps Followed:
    In WMQ V7.0 Explorer, Right click on JMS Administered Objects -> Add Inital Context -> select
    File System -> Gave name in Bindings directory (C:/JNDI_Directory) -> Gave 
    Context nickname(file:/C:/JNDI_Directory/) and click finish.

```
In connectionFactory, the context nickname will be set as file:/C:/JNDI_Directory/ -> then click on New -> Gave connection factory name (JMSConnectionFactory)
and select messaging provider as, Websphere MQ -> select the connection factory -> select transport as MQ Client -> 
Select base queue manager(JMS_QMGR) and connection list(localhost(2525)) in the connection tab.

In Destination -> new -> Destination -> enter the name of destination(JMSDestination) and type of queue -> select Queue Manager and queue in general tab

In Worklight creating worklight project name as TestJMSAdapter and created a jms adapter(JMSAdapter), configured the following in JMSAdapter.xml file.


<namingConnection url="file:/C:/JNDI_Directory/"  initialContextFactory="com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory"/>

<jmsConnection connectionFactory="JMSConnectionFactory" />

In JMSAdapter-impl.js, configure the destination as follows,
readMessage(){
           return WL.Server.readSingleJMSMessage({
                                        destination: "JMSDestination",
                                        timeout: 60
                                        });
                     }
```

and took all jars from /WebSphere MQ/java/lib, added the following jars in lib folder:

```
/TestJMSAdapter/server/lib/com.ibm.mq.commonservices.jar
/TestJMSAdapter/server/lib/com.ibm.mq.headers.jar
/TestJMSAdapter/server/lib/com.ibm.mq.jar
/TestJMSAdapter/server/lib/com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar
/TestJMSAdapter/server/lib/com.ibm.mq.jms.Nojndi.jar
/TestJMSAdapter/server/lib/com.ibm.mqjms.jar
/TestJMSAdapter/server/lib/dhbcore.jar
/TestJMSAdapter/server/lib/fscontext.jar
/TestJMSAdapter/server/lib/jms.jar
/TestJMSAdapter/server/lib/jndi.jar
/TestJMSAdapter/server/lib/providerutil.jar
```

I'm using worklight v6 and deployed in (WebSphere Application Server V8.5 Liberty)Worklight Development Server.

while invoking the procedure it shows the following error:

Error in Worklight Development Server console is,

```
[ERROR ] FWLSE0005W: JMS connection exception received: com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory cannot be cast to javax.jms.ConnectionFactory. Closing the connection. [project TestJMSAdapter]
```

Please help me out.

Comment: Here are some steps to debug. 
A. Look at the MQ error logs in <MQ_INSTALL_PATH>/errors and <MQ_INSTALL_PATH>/Qmgrs/<QMGR_NAME>/errors and observe if you see any errors that are related 
B. Check the app server logs (turn on tracing if required). Most often, you will find an Exception and its stack trace which will point to the cause of the error / failure. 

I noticed that your MQ listener port is not the default (2525). Have you ensured that the listener on that port is running and that the connection factory has the right information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are seeing is usually caused by the incorrect jars being added to your project.

You have two options:

- Find out which jars need to be removed.

I believe the jar that is causing your problem is the "jms.jar" file. Remove that file and try again.

- Upgrade to the latest version of Worklight.

All classloading issues have been fixed in the latest version of worklight, so regardless of the jars that are included it should still work.

Comment: I have removed the "jms.jar", now I got "[ERROR   ] FWLSE0006E: Received JMS Message of unsupported type: null. Message ignored. [project TestJMSAdapter]" error. I'm using the updated version. - IBM Worklight Server Version 6.0.0 - Included IBM Worklight Studio V6.0.0.201306140701 plugin in eclipse juno(4.2.2) How can I proceed now?

Comment: Great, now your adapter is working and you are receiving the message from your backend. Currently, the Worklight adapter only supports the TextMessage data type. It looks like your backend is sending a message of a different type. The message "unsupported type: null" appears to be a defect that will be logged, as it should be displaying the data type of the message you are sending. Try checking which type of message is being sent and see if its possible to make it a text message instead.

Comment: Also, if you believe that the JMS adapter should support other data types, you can submit a feature request to have this added.

Comment: Solved. I have changed the format as text instead of xml. Its working fine. thanks!